# Can p(1,2)= 1 and p(2,4)=3 be linear opperators?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vectors

This is a linear algebra question...[image]

```
 So I know that the two conditions for linearity are additivity and homogeneity.
```

Typically Ives seen examples where the functions are L(1,2)= (2,5). However the functions I am trying to prove to be linear seem to be equal to scalars. Am I wrong to think that I can only use the condition of homogeneity?

```
  L(cv)= cL(v)
```

Any clarity on proving this would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Scalars form a vector space as well.  Just as polynomials naturally form a vector space, and continuous functions, and sequences which converge to zero, etc...  That it equals a scalar is utterly irrelevant.  Ask yourself, what is twice $\binom{1}{2}$?  If $p$ was in fact linear, what should that equal?  Given your conditions, is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(2,4)= p((1,2)+(1,2))=p(1,2)+p(1,2)=1+1=2\neq3,$$
so $p$ is non linear.

Comment: the function is $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, and both spaces are vector spaces so you can construct linear functions between them, you don't necessarily need to have the same domain and codomain to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You want $x+2y=1$ and $2x+4y=3\implies x+2y=\frac{3}{2}$

This is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is the same as asking: "are there scalars $a$ and $b$ so that $a \cdot 1+ b \cdot 2 = 1$ and $a \cdot 2 + b \cdot 4 = 3$."  You should be able to show easily that this is impossible, so the function is not linear.